# Improving MIDI Synthesizer Sound on Android / Loading Sound Fonts

Tags: java, android, midi

I recently started to build an Android App that will make heavy use of MIDI sounds. Problem: The standard Android MIDI sound is just horrible. On Windows and Linux, I vastly improved the sound by applying a soundfont (.sf2) - that doesn't seem to be possible on Android without further ado.

While looking for a solution, `EAS_LoadDLSCollection()` popped up a few times, but as I'm pretty new to Android programming, I can't figure out how to make use of it.

It's not mandatory that the MIDI sound is changed system wide - just for the app would be enough.

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: did you come with a solution for this? I am very interested on an answer too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks possible using [FluidSynth](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fluidsynth/). You'll have to compile it for the JNI, though. Steps to do so can be found on [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8201#c38) about it. There are some other interesting comments in that thread, also.